# Get CSSKeyframesRule length

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, variable-length

I'm iterating through a CSS keyframe in order to change the original to a new animation based on the keyframe that is closest the current behavior of the element being animated. I use the function below to obtain the keyframe rules by iterating through the stylesheets.

```
function findKeyframesRule(rule) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++j) {
            if (ss[i].cssRules[j].type == window.CSSRule.WEBKIT_KEYFRAMES_RULE 
               && ss[i].cssRules[j].name == rule) { 
                return  ss[i].cssRules[j]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

called like so: `var keyframes = findKeyframesRule(anim);`

**My Problem:** I need to get the length/size of `ss[i].cssRules[j]` (or the variable `keyframes` because they point to the same WebkitCSSKeyframesRule object) but have been unable to find a way to do so. I found what I think is the source for CSSKeyframesRules [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/CSSKeyframesRule.cpp), but it is in C, so I am unable to use the methods they use to find the length/size, i.e. `::length` and such.

I know it has a length because I can call things like `keyframes[3].keyText` and get a value, so it *acts* like an array.

I have tried `keyframes.size()`, `keyframes.forEach`, `keyframes.length`, and some more attempts but they don't work because it's not an array, it's a CSSKeyframesRule object. I also attempted work arounds using the ¿parent? (I don't what to call it - I mean `ss`, `ss[i]`, and `ss[i].cssRules`) including `ss[i].cssRules.length` which I thought would work but it doesn't.

[Here is a fiddle to show my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/u8bwa/3/)

Do any of you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Just try to alert

> keyframes.cssRules.length

will get 5

```
alert(keyframes.cssRules.length);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/creativevilla/T83Nc/

Comment: *Facepalm* Thank you for catching that. I have been looking at this for hours and hadn't thought of it!